# Почему не получается подключить модуль requests?

Tags: python, requests

В командной строке написала pip install requests, затем pip list(requests есть в списке). Вроде всё получилось, но когда в коде пишу `import requests`, пишет ошибку: *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'*. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так

Comment: А питон из того же каталога и вообще окруджения запускается, где `pip`? Установок питона может быть много.

Comment: Убедитесь что pip работает с нужной Вам версией питона. Может быть что у Вас установлено несколько версий питона